# Query Cloudant Views with OR condition

Tags: cloudant

I know that we can query a View with multiple keys and complex keys. But the search keys by default execute on a AND condition. Is it possible to query a view with multiple search strings using an OR condition?

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to query MapReduce views with an "or" condition. There are two possible solutions:

- execute two separate MapReduce queries (in series or parallel) and aggregate the results
- depending on your use-case, consider [Cloudant Search](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/search.html#search) or [Cloudant Query](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html#query), both of which allow two search clauses to be OR'd together